# Format eclipse so annotations not on different lines, but are on their own line

Tags: eclipse, formatting

Say I have a method in Eclipse like so:

```
@Deprecated
@Override
public void foo(int i) {
    super(i+1);
}
```

If I go to the formatter in eclipse, New Lines tab, and uncheck `Insert new line after annotation on members`, I get the following

```
@Deprecated @Override public void foo(int i) {
    super(i+1);
}
```

But what I actually want is in between the two:

```
@Deprecated @Override // annotations here
public void foo(int i) { // method here
    super(i+1);
}
```

Is this possible in Eclipse?